# windows smtp server to send sms ? who can help me

Tags: windows-10, email, smtp

I am trying to setup a `smtp` server on my windows 10 vps server. I would like to use it for sending sms. I tried a few softwares that are free but none worked.

In particular, I tried to install this [software](https://www.hmailserver.com/).

The software wants to install `Microsoft Network Framework 2.0`, and here the issue is the file is not found on the Microsoft website to download?  Is this something that is outdated and not possible to get anywhere anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as the "Microsoft Network Framework". You probably mean the "Microsoft Net Framework", which can be found on the Microsoft site for download, but version 2 of that framework is very, very old, and any software that requires it, particularly communication server software, is going to be a problem based either on its age or on the fact it requires seriously outdated frameworks like this.

So, you're probably just looking for the wrong thing, and that is easily fixed now that you know the correct name, but you should also find a different piece of software to accomplish what you're trying, especially on an internet-facing system like this.

Answer (score 0):

From [OperaVPS](https://operavps.com/docs/install-smtp-server-on-windows/) : "Please be aware that Windows 11, Windows 10, and Windows 8 are not able to function as SMTP Servers. The SMTP server is a part of Windows Server’s IIS (Internet Information Services). The SMTP email client is included with the client operating systems but not an SMTP server." That said, there may be [workarounds](https://linuxhint.com/set-up-smtp-server-windows/) in Windows 10.

However, since Win10 is near end of life, and since *both* Windows 10 and 11 have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), it might be easier to install a Linux distro such as Ubuntu, and then install a [Postfix SMTP server](https://linuxhint.com/set-up-an-smtp-server-ubuntu/), which can be done in just a few lines on terminal. It might be even easier and more reliable to create a stand-alone Ubuntu instance, either dual-boot or *just* Ubuntu, rather than relying on the intermediate Windows 10, with its own firewall rules.